# Stopping command prompt from showing current directory in windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

How do I stop the command prompt from showing c:\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4 It gets really annoying when I'm 5 or 6 directories deep.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `prompt`:

```
C:\Stuff> prompt $$
$ prompt $G
> prompt $N:$G
c:> prompt Hello
Hello (etc)
```

Use `help prompt` to see some more options.

Answer (score 5):

I use `prompt $p$_$g$s` (actually in my environment variables).
Thus I have the current path, always useful, a new line and the classical > and a space.
Even at the deep level of folders, I have plenty of room for my commands.

Comment: Thanks! Clever use of $_ to get a new line in the prompt!

Answer (score 3):

With the prompt command.  Type the following a the command line to find out how to use it:

```
prompt /?
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the environment variable "prompt" to "$g", (or whatever). To do this: right click the My Computer icon, select Properties, click on the Advanced tab, there's a button for Environment Variables.

Answer (score 0):

You could use prompt.
Have a batch file in system32 called go with

```
cd %1
prompt Love And Kittens$G
```

and type go c:\ to goto c:\, but still be faced with a cute command prompt :3
($G is the >, other special symbols are shown in /?)

Answer (score 0):

or maybe **cd \**