# How do I hide the path in command line prompt on Windows?

Tags: command-line, path, prompt

I'm working on Windows 7 using the cmd console.
How do I hide the path in the prompt?

Comment: why do you want to?

Comment: real-estate ...

Comment: Sorry, dont follow. You mean you want to see more on the screen?

Comment: That's what he means, exactly.

Comment: -1 extremely badly worded, and maybe not even the best thing to do if you're bothered by a long current directory. A better thing might be prompt $p$_$g. So you still are reminded of the current directory but it's not in the way. And if you did want to hide the current directory, then it's not hiding the path it's hiding the current directory. And of course it can still be seen by CD if you meant hiding it from people. Your question is pretty bad. And adding the comment about "real-estate" shows no care to ensure clarity, and no ability to use proper terms, and no care about using proper terms

Comment: @barlop, I believe real estate is a fairly standard way to refer to the space available on the screen - e.g. http://www.bing.com/search?q=screen+real+estate&form=OPRTSD&pc=OPER

Comment: @dsolimano well he could've put that in his question, and anyhow, one can increase the size of the window if they want more "real-estate".  and he meant current directory.  he could've been specific and said the issue he has is when typing after the long prompt, the text wraps too soon when he's in a directory with a long path, so he wants to make the prompt smaller, so space -there-. All he asked in his question about was "hiding the path"  well that could be hiding the PATH variable. It's a very badly worded question. very cavalier

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stopping command prompt from showing current directory in windows XP?](http://superuser.com/questions/35237/stopping-command-prompt-from-showing-current-directory-in-windows-xp)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can use

```
prompt [text]
```

command. Type `prompt /?` to list all of the [available parameters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/prompt). For example, the following command sets "> (greater-than sign)" as prompt.

```
prompt $g
```

Comment: I feel FREE!!!!

Comment: Is there a way to make this stick ie become default?

Comment: Does this all need admin rights? When I type `prompt` on the Windows10 machine I'm on now, it just prints the prompt out twice and does nothing. Doesn't matter what I type after it ... `/?` `$g` ...makes no difference

Answer (score 10):

The command `prompt $g` will indeed set the prompt to a single `>` sign. For a full list of special codes you can use there, see `prompt /?`.

If you want the custom prompt to apply automatically when you start a command prompt, you can set the `PROMPT` environment variable. That can be accomplished [in the normal Windows UI](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm), or by using the `setx` command. For example, this sets the prompt to `>` :

```
setx PROMPT $g$s
```

On the next launch of the command prompt, you'll see your new prompt.

To restore the normal Windows prompt for one session, type `prompt`. To restore the default for all sessions by removing the environment variable, type `setx PROMPT ""`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks @Ben N

Comment: typing `setx PROMPT $g$s` gives me `ERROR: Invalid syntax. Type "SETX /?" for usage.`

Comment: @PandaWood Make sure to run that in a classic command prompt (CMD) instead of PowerShell. The dollar signs indicate a PowerShell variable. Also please note that the `PROMPT` environment variable only affects CMD, not the PowerShell prompt.

Answer (score 8):

Some more tips:

If you want to go back to previous status (showing full path), just type `prompt` without any arguments, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If you just want to see current working directory (the same as `pwd` in linux), type `chdir` or `cd` without any arguments and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.