# How I get my command prompt to show just the name of the folder I'm in (not the whole path))

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe, path, prompt

In a command prompt window (terminal), how can I get my prompt to be just the current folder?

e.g.

```
prompt $p $g
```

gives:

```
C:\Users\Robin >
```

But I want it to just show:

```
Robin >
```

UPDATE: As @Caius Jard said in the comments, the question identified doesn't duplicate this, as I don't want to simply remove the path, I want to have the current folder name included in the prompt.

e.g.

```
 Program Files >
```

or

```
 Users >
```

Hope that clarifies

Comment: Duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/315354/how-do-i-hide-the-path-in-command-line-prompt-on-windows

Answer is to use the following command

'prompt $g'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I hide the path in command line prompt on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/315354/how-do-i-hide-the-path-in-command-line-prompt-on-windows)

Comment: Not exactly: `prompt $g` will just show `>` as the prompt, not `name_of_current_folder>` as prompt - which is what he wants. i.e. he wants the folder he is in, without any of the path above it, and a > as his prompt

Comment: PowerShell can apparently do this -- https://superuser.com/questions/446827/configure-the-windows-powershell-to-display-only-the-current-folder-name-in-the

Comment: Thanks @CaiusJard.  You're absolutely right, thanks.  I've clarified the question above.

Comment: Thank @Anaksunaman, I've switched to PowerShell, and the question you linked to has done the job.  Took a bit of fiddling (setting up profile, setting ExecutionPolicy (to Unrestricted, unfortunately, *gulp*), but it's working

Comment: @robinmckenzie eek! Well, glad it's working, regardless. =P